# Convertir un Array ASCII a String Swift 4

Tags: array, swift, string, ascii

Estoy haciendo una app en swift 4 de encriptado y desencriptado, la pregunta empieza aquí. cuando DESENCRIPTO me regresa una Array con los valores en  **ASCII Array**

> [109, 105, 32, 109, 101, 110, 115, 97, 106, 101, 32, 111, 99, 117, 108, 116, 111]     // String encriptado -> "mi mensaje oculto".

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo convertir el **Array ASCII** en el mensaje que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De esta manera puedes convertir una matriz de tipo UInt8 a una cadena

```
 let cadenaEncriptada: [UInt8] = [109, 105, 32, 109, 101, 110, 115, 97, 106, 101, 32, 111, 99, 117, 108, 116, 111]
 if let valor = String(bytes: cadenaEncriptada, encoding: .utf8) {
     print(valor)
 }
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto!